# How to make a string get the text of a specific line of a listbox by checking if the line contains certain text?

Tags: c#, listbox

does anybody know how to make a string in c# get the text of a certain (unselected) line of a listbox? I've tried (this has itemselected):

```
string text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string[] stringy = text.Split(' ');
MessageBox.Show(stringy[1]);
```

But that requires an item to be selected. If it was possible, this is what i'm trying to do:

```
string text = listBox1.GetLine.ThatContainsText("stuff stuff stuff");
string[] stringy = text.Split(' ');
MessageBox.Show(string[1]);
```

If somebody could help, that would be great. If you need me to provide anything else, I can.

Comment: Wow, theres a notorious downvoter on the run.

Comment: So are you just checking to see if your listbox contains a list item that matches a string or do you want to select the list item as well?

Comment: It's quite simple. Everyone is forgetting that `Items` returns an `ObjectCollection` and that you must call `Cast<string>` to have an `IEnumerable<string>` to call LINQ operations on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var textToSearchFor = "stuff stuff stuff";
var text = (from x in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
           where x.Contains(textToSearchFor)
           select x)
           .FirstOrDefault(); //maybe even single, depending on your input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = (from x in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
            where x.Contains("stuff stuff stuff") 
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    string[] stringy = text.Split(' ');
    MessageBox.Show(string[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
String text = (String)listBox.Items
    .FirstOrDefault(i => ((String)i).Contains("stuff stuff stuff"));
```

Comment: `Items` is an `ObjectCollection` that implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`; you have to call `Cast<string>` if you want to use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = (String)listBox.Items.Cast<string>()
.FirstOrDefault(i => ((String)i).Contains("stuff stuff stuff") && !i.Equals(listBox.SelectedItem));
```

Sorry for non-formated response, I'm writting this from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that works if you're trying to get an exact match.

```
var text = listBox1.Items.FindByText("stuff stuff stuff");
```

Otherwise you'll have to use

```
var text = (from x in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
            where x.Contains("stuff stuff stuff")
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then just verify that 'text' isn't null

```
if (text != null)
{
    string[] stringy = text.ToString().Split(' ');
    MessageBox.Show(stringy[1]);
}
```